# How to check existence of a file with a relative path in C++

Tags: c++

I have  a relative path string and I would like to check if this file exists or not.
I know I can check it with tring to open it - when I have an absolute path:

```
filestream.open(filename.c_str(),fstream::in);
```

(and checking if the file was open or not)
but how can I do it when I have a relative path?

Comment: do you have access to the boost c++ libraries?

Comment: No. I saw this solution.

Comment: which OS is targeted? Which libraries can/do you use? Not nearly enough information to answer this.

Comment: Why do you think you can't do the same thing with a relative path? (Hint: you can. It will be relative to the 'current directory' that you ran the program from.)

Comment: Checking if a file exists is not the right thing to do. You need to try the operation you want to do on the file directly instead, and then figure out why it failed if it does.

Comment: `filestream.open` will work equally well with a relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With relative paths, the question is always "relative to what?"

Consult your standard library's documentation to see how it interprets relative paths passed as arguments when opening a file stream. My guess is it will interpret it relative to the current working directory of the process. If that's what you want, just use the relative path directly.

If that's *not* what you want, then you know what your want it relative to. Just prepend that; this will give you an absolute path, which you can pass on to a file stream constructor or `open()`.